Tool to repair exFAT Partition (upcase table corrupted)
I have a NVME SSD with a 4 TB exFAT partition. It is still readable in both linux and windows, but it had some corrupted files due to abruptly power off of my NAS Host. Still most of files and folders seemed to be okay. I tried running chkdsk on windows and also fsck.exfat (from exfatprogs) in Ubuntu.
fsck.exfat accused some corrupted entries in some files and folders, and performed some fixes. Then I thought it was clean, but when trying copying/deleting/creating some files, I encountered some errors that clearly showed that some problems are still not corrected. So I tried CHKDSK on it, but it was running for days  (and still 0%) and kept finding errors on "\FOUND.000" (368846). This counter in parenthesis started from 0 and are already on 368846 but increasing in a very slow rate (that is why it was running for days).
I then stopped it and went to linux, where the FOUND.000 folder seems empty. I ran again a fsck.exfat and it corrected many entries. Then running CHKDSK again, it kept finding errors inside FOUND.000.
Now both CHKDSK and fsck.exfat accuse "upcase table corrupted" or wrong. I havent found though any good software for correcting exFAT partitions, especially correcting the upcase table. fsck.exfat detects the problem but wont correct it. CHKDSK may solve it in the end but I am afraid it is gonna run for months, because in 4-5 days it was still finding wrong entries under FOUND.000 and the whole process was sill 0% finished.
Can someone suggest any good tool that might fix this kind of issue?
AOMEI, EaseUS, Recoverit were of no use. I'm currently running TestDisk, triggered an analysis of the partition but after reaching 32% it got quite slow.. reading 1 cylinder every 2s, and I still have some more 300.000 cyilinders left to be checked...
Any further help is appreciated.

Have you tried the other fsck.exfat? There are two: exfat-utils and exfatprogs, the latter being more up-to-date.

I tried only the one from exfatprogs, exactly because it seemed the more up-to-date and correct one to be used now. Not sure if I remember correct but the other one only checks but wont perform any correction on exFAT partitions, right? But I can try to see.. currently is still running a check from DiskGenius
